# GAE does not release memory after handling request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Why does this happen?

I run a task which uses a lot of memory - after the task has finished I would expect the memory to be released back to the instance.

However, this doesn't happen. The memory just keeps going up and up on subsequent execution of the task until eventually I get a soft memory warning.

What can I do about this? It just doesn't make sense. I have tried explicitly calling `gc.collect()` but this doesn't help.

Comment: You'll need to show some code.

Comment: Does your task import a lot of stuff? GAE caches imports.

Comment: @Bugs OK, new information - but why would a subsequent run of the task increase the memory usage again?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I will try and knock up a toy example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @HorseloverFat it's really hard to say without knowing exactly what's going on in your code.

Comment: +1 for your nick, sir.

Comment: It's called a memory leak.  Most likely your code, or a library you're using, is not releasing memory.  Memory allocated to a global variables could cause easily cause this.

Comment: @dragonx I think the GAE interactive console has a memory leak. When I tried repeatedly running same task from http request (as opposed to from within the interactive console) I no longer saw the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you using ndb / reading / writing significantly?  Try set_cache_policy() or clear_cache()

Answer (score 0):

Like dragonx wrote every handler which was run, every global variable, import is cached on GAE so how long your instance is running so big she is. You can reconfigure your app settings to faster creating new instances and killing old's. That will give you a little chance to minimize that error.
That error doesn't have to be populated because of memory leaks. Many things affect to that so you should check your code, try to reconfigure your instance settings and maybe you should change your instance type to higher.